# Django: How to update user model without updating user password field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a user update endpoint that only updates select fields of a user. My currently implementation is to save the model with ModelForm's save method but I've also tried with the base model save method.

My request body doesn't contain a password field and I don't have a password field in my UserForm, however I'm unable to maintain the current session or logout and log back in with the current user after executing an update. I'm nearly positive this is because Django is changing my password somewhere during the update process.

Other pertinent information: I'm using Django (not Django Rest Framework). I have a custom user model. I know I can solve this issue by using serializers with DRF but it seems hacky to use that for this issue alone.

My endpoint looks like this:

```
def saveAccountData (request):
    resp = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            resp['result'] = 'User updated'
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(resp),
                status=200
            )
        else:
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(form.errors),
                status=422,
            )
```

My Form looks like this:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'name', 'is_active', 'is_admin']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.name = self.cleaned_data['name']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

User model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.conf import settings
import logging

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        # executes if email is zero (false) or an empty container (equivalent to None)
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.warning('Create user: ' + password)
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Please provide an email address")

        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Please enter a password")

        if not name:
            raise ValueError("Please enter your name")

        # normalize email address (convert to lower case so all email addresses are standardized)
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            name=name,
        )
        # the set_password method encrypts the password
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, name):
        user = self.create_user(
            email, 
            password=password, 
            name=name)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()
    # we must specify a username field
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # required fields are used for create_superuser
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        # django uses this method when it needs to convert an object to a string
        return self.email
```

Comment: Are you sure its changing your password? You have the is_active field as part of your form, is that keeping your user active after you save? Its not a normal django thing to change password after user model update.

Comment: What's the point of the custom form save method? `name` is a field on the form and the model, it will be saved automatically along with all the others.

Comment: The point of the custom save method is to allow for partial updates however I haven't fully built it. That configuration was designed to test behavior and prevent password from updating. 

I will look into the is_active issue thanks.

Comment: There's really no need for a custom save method for this. Only the fields you specify in your form will be updated in any case.

Comment: Thanks @devdob is_active and is_admin were both getting set to false which I missed somehow.

And yea Daniel you're right I don't need one. Thanks.

Comment: Well I only know that cuz I made that mistake once before. Glad it works!

Answer (score 1):

I created a UpdateAccountForm(forms.ModelForm),
and overwrite save() like:

```

```
  class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['username', 'groups', 'is_active']

  def save(self, commit=True):
  ┆   user = super(UpdateAccountForm, self).save(commit=False)
  ┆   password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
  ┆   if password:
  ┆   ┆   user.set_password(password)
  ┆   if commit:
  ┆   ┆   user.save()
  ┆   return user
```

```